# How to assign a unique number per group of entries in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of part numbers in Column A and a location in Column S.  I need to assign a value of 1 for all part numbers that are the same (A3-A16), then change to a value of 2 when the part number changes (A18-A22), and so on a so forth.  Basically, all like part numbers will have a unique value starting at one and ending when the data ends.  Help?

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a database and not excel.  Is the data sorted by part number or could your unique numbers be in a sequence like 1,1,2,3,1,3,2,etc

Comment: Are these kind of questions allowed in the FAQ?

Comment: It was a last minute requirement and I needed to get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** column A is sorted, then put `1` in X1 and `=IF(A2=A1;X1;X1+1)` (change all the X's to the column where you want the part number). Copy-paste X2 down as far as needed.

As an (bit more complex) alternative, you can follow [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx#BMcount_the_number_of_unique_values_by_) suggestion by Microsoft and put this formula in X1 and copy-paste down: `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY($A$1:A1,$A$1:A1)>0,1))`. Using this solution, the data in column A doesn't need to be sorted.

Comment: Thank you agtoever, super simple and I totally have done that before, but couldn't get it out of my brain.